# Problema con ifs en blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, condiciones

Hola tengo esta tabla es una tabla de calificaciones promedio, mi problema es que necesito la siguiente validación.

Si la calificación es menor igual a 5 que la celda aparezca en fondo rojo.
Si es mayor a 5 pero menor igual que 7 que aparezca en amarillo.
Si es mayor a 7 pero menor igual o menor a 10 que sea color verde.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo realice la siguiente validación con los condicionales de blade, el color rojo me lo aplica correctamente, el problema inicia en la segunda validación. Aquí se hace una suma de dos valores ya que son los tomados en cuenta para sacar el promedio, sumados y divididos entre dos para que de correctamente.

Este es el codigo

```
                    <tbody>

                    @foreach ($reportes as $reporte)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$reporte->id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$reporte->user->name}} {{$reporte->user->surname}}</td>
                        <td>{{$reporte->empresa->nombre}}</td>
                        <td>{{$reporte->calificacionA}}</td>
                        <td>{{$reporte->calificacionB}}</td>
                        <td>{{$reporte->tEventuales}}</td>
                        <td>{{$reporte->tPlanta}}</td>
                        <td>{{$reporte->tEventuales + $reporte->tPlanta}}</td>

                        @if(($reporte->calificacionA+$reporte->calificacionB/2) <=5)

                        <td style="background-color:#c82333;">{{($reporte->calificacionA + $reporte->calificacionB)/2}}</td>

                        @elseif(($reporte->calificacionA+$reporte->calificacionB/2) >=6 || ($reporte->calificacionA+$reporte->calificacionB/2) <7)

                        <td style="background-color:#d39e00;">{{($reporte->calificacionA + $reporte->calificacionB)/2}}</td>

                        @elseif(($reporte->calificacionA+$reporte->calificacionB/2) >= 7 && ($reporte->calificacionA+$reporte->calificacionB/2) <=10)

                        <td style="background-color:#1e7e34;">{{($reporte->calificacionA + $reporte->calificacionB)/2}}</td>

                        @endif


                    </tr>
                    @endforeach

                </tbody>
```

Este es el controlador que manda los datos a la vista.

```
    public function index(){

    $reportes = Report::all();

    $color = "#c82333";

    foreach($reportes as $reporte){
        $promedio = $reporte->calificacionA + $reporte->calificacionB/2;
    }


    if ($promedio >= 8) {

        $color = '#1e7e34';

    } elseif ($promedio >= 6) {

        $color = '#d39e00';

    }


    return view('reports.index', [
        'reportes' => $reportes,
        'promedio' => $promedio,
        'color' => $color,
    ]);
}
```

y este fue el resultado en la vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Es posible que la calificación sea mayor a 10?

Comment: No la calificación solo puede estar entre el rango de 1 y 10.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código como texto y no como imagen.

Comment: Listo ya acabo de poner el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay mucha lógica en tu vista, y mucho código que se repite, yo pasaría la mayor parte de la lógica al controlador y en la vista simplemente el color resultante según la condición, pero te voy a dar la solución genérica y tú lo pasas al controlador o a Blade, según como manejes la información:

```
// asignamos un color por defecto, así ahorramos una condición
$color = '#c82333';

// calculamos el promedio solo una vez
$promedio = $reporte->calificacionA+$reporte->calificacionB/2;

if ($promedio >= 7) {
    $color = '#1e7e34';
} elseif ($promedio >= 6) {
    $color = '#d39e00';
}
```

Y en la vista tendrías simplemente esto:

```
<td style="background-color:{{$color}};">{{($promedio}}</td>
```

Comment: Ya había intentado hacer la lógica en el controlador pero por alguna razón no funciono, me podrías decir donde esta mi error? así quedo mi tabla con la soluciona que me diste. Edite la pregunta arriba puse el código.

Comment: ¿Cuál error? yo no veo ningún error...

Comment: No en tu código, si no en el mio acabo de ponerlo arriba. Podrías indicarme que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Está explicado en mi respuesta, lo que estás intentando hacer (el código que muestras en la pregunta) es una forma arcaica de resolver el problema.